# Regarding keeping some specific formatted string while removing others for a given column

Tags: regex, windows, excel, vba

In the excel file, some columns have cell value such as following

```
ABCDE-4567  1234
```

I would like to keep `ABCDE-4567` and remove `1234` for that specific cell. In other words, if there is a numerical value which does not associate with any other strings, we should remove it. Since `4567` is connected with `ABCDE` via `-`, we should keep it. How to do that in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If all you values are as in your example, you can do this by searching for the first space (`" "`) in your cell and then return all characters from the left and until that point.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```